# Inference on LSTM model. RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I have built a LSTM model and it works fine when training but  when i try to do inference on a test set i run into the following error.

```
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [698, 200] at entry 0 and [70, 200] at entry 1
```

df_test is a dataframe with one text column. I dont understand why i get two values, e.g. 698 and 200 above. I should get only one, 200. The problem seems to be in the dataset class or the dataloader. I am pretty new to pytorch so i cant figure out how to solve it. I am using a tokenizer from keras.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

df_test = pd.read_csv("/content/comments_to_score.csv")

tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df_test.text.values.tolist())
```

```
class TestDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df, tokenizer):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.df = df
        self.text = df['text'].values
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        text = self.text[index]

        text_tokens = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
        
        text_out = pad_sequences(text_tokens, padding="post", truncating="post", maxlen=200)
        
        return {
            'text': torch.tensor(text_out, dtype=torch.long)
        }
```

```
import gc
@torch.no_grad()
def valid_fn(model, dataloader, device):
    model.eval()
    
    dataset_size = 0
    running_loss = 0.0
    
    PREDS = []
    
    bar = tqdm(enumerate(dataloader), total=len(dataloader))
    for step, data in bar:
        text = data['text'].to(device)
        
        outputs = model(text)
        PREDS.append(outputs.view(-1).cpu().detach().numpy()) 
    
    PREDS = np.concatenate(PREDS)
    gc.collect()
    
    return PREDS
```

```
def inference(model_paths, dataloader, device):
    final_preds = []
    for i, path in enumerate(model_paths):
        model = LSTM(embedding_matrix)
        model.to(CONFIG['device'])
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path))
        
        print(f"Getting predictions for model {i+1}")
        
        preds = valid_fn(model, dataloader, device)
        print(f'length of predictions = {len(preds)}')
        #print(f'predictions = {preds}')
        final_preds.append(preds)
    
    final_preds = np.array(final_preds)
    final_preds = np.mean(final_preds, axis=0)
    return final_preds
```

```
test_dataset = TestDataset(df_test, tokenizer = tokenizer)

test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=CONFIG['test_batch_size'], shuffle=False, pin_memory=True)
```

```
MODEL_PATHS = ["/content/LSTM-model-exp7-1.bin", "/content/LSTM-model-exp7-2.bin"]

preds = inference(MODEL_PATHS, test_loader, CONFIG['device'])
```

Here is the full output of the error:

```
<ipython-input-37-a0852b900549> in inference(model_paths, dataloader, device)
      8         print(f"Getting predictions for model {i+1}")
      9 
---> 10         preds = valid_fn(model, dataloader, device)
     11         print(f'length of predictions = {len(preds)}')
     12         #print(f'predictions = {preds}')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     26         def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     27             with self.__class__():
---> 28                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     29         return cast(F, decorate_context)
     30 

<ipython-input-36-50ba36440090> in valid_fn(model, dataloader, device)
     10 
     11     bar = tqdm(enumerate(dataloader), total=len(dataloader))
---> 12     for step, data in bar:
     13         text = data['text'].to(device)
     14 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tqdm/std.py in __iter__(self)
   1178 
   1179         try:
-> 1180             for obj in iterable:
   1181                 yield obj
   1182                 # Update and possibly print the progressbar.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    519             if self._sampler_iter is None:
    520                 self._reset()
--> 521             data = self._next_data()
    522             self._num_yielded += 1
    523             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    559     def _next_data(self):
    560         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 561         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    562         if self._pin_memory:
    563             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     50         else:
     51             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 52         return self.collate_fn(data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in default_collate(batch)
     72         return batch
     73     elif isinstance(elem, collections.abc.Mapping):
---> 74         return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in elem}
     75     elif isinstance(elem, tuple) and hasattr(elem, '_fields'):  # namedtuple
     76         return elem_type(*(default_collate(samples) for samples in zip(*batch)))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
     72         return batch
     73     elif isinstance(elem, collections.abc.Mapping):
---> 74         return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in elem}
     75     elif isinstance(elem, tuple) and hasattr(elem, '_fields'):  # namedtuple
     76         return elem_type(*(default_collate(samples) for samples in zip(*batch)))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in default_collate(batch)
     54             storage = elem.storage()._new_shared(numel)
     55             out = elem.new(storage)
---> 56         return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
     57     elif elem_type.__module__ == 'numpy' and elem_type.__name__ != 'str_' \
     58             and elem_type.__name__ != 'string_':

RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [698, 200] at entry 0 and [70, 200] at entry 1
```

Can anyone figure out what is wrong here?

Comment: I suspect that you are getting less records in the last batch of test_dataset. Do you have something like drop_remainder option in your dataloader?

Comment: I get the error already on the first batch. But i tried drop_last=True anyway but it did not work. Same error.